# In Windows 8 WPF app, is there any UI control which can work with "StartPreviewAsync" of "MediaCapture" class?

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I have been developing Windows 8 WPF app and want to preview WebCam. In WinRT, there is straight forward "MediaCapture" class which provides "StartPreviewAsync" function. In Metro style app, there is "CaptureElement" UI control which allows to directly assign MediaCapture to its "Source" property. But in WPF there is not. Any help how can I use MediaCapture facility to preview webcam into WPF app ?  I have tried with WPF "MediaElemnet" but couldn't find way to feed "MediCapture's" web cam feed into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an ancient question, but I hate seeing questions without responses. When you say Windows 8 WPF, what you're really talking about is just WPF 4.5.  There is no equivalent to this in WPF and I highly doubt there ever will be.  Your best bet in WPF is to use Jeremiah Morrill's [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) which supports capturing from a web cam source.